# Problem moving from axios 0.27.2 to 1.4 on WSL

Tags: ubuntu, next.js, axios, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When i upgrade my app to axios 1.4 it fails my WSL machine, it can't reach my api

```
const headers = { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`
return await axios.post(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/graphql`, JSON.stringify(query), { headers: headers })
```

it returns the error 404 'Not Found' and somehow the host on the request changes to 'verdaccio.local' which is my private proxy registry, i just don't know i got there

it works fine with axios:0.27.2, it also works on other PC

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Node: 18.17.1
next: 13.2.4